# I recently upgraded jenkins to version 2.6. Why do some of the plugins ask me to downgrade them?

Tags: jenkins

I have recent upgrade Jenkin to 2.6. However some of the plugins want to be downgraded to 1.14.1.

[image]Is there something missing from my upgrade? The Java version where the Jenkins is located is currently 1.7 do I need to upgrade it to 1.8?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the plugins?

Comment: @CSchulz Not sure what type of screenshot you need compare to what I have already posted(screenshot of plugins). Can you provide a bit more info.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the screenshot, these plugins offer the option of downgrading. 
Unless you get specific warnings in the UI or the logfile there is no need to touch these buttons.

As part of the Jenkins upgrade these plugins were also updated. 
In case these newer version introduce unwanted behaviour the system allows you to revert back to the previous version. 
If you update a plugin from the plugin manager you get the same option.